# Find articles that have been tagged as X and Y but not as Z

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Let's say I have Articles that can have many Tags. I'd like to be able to find all articles that have been tagged as X and Y, but not Z.

The database looks something like this:

**articles**

- id
- title
- body

**tags**

- id
- name

**articles_tags**

- article_id
- tag_id

Now, if I wanted to find all articles that have been tagged as both X and Y, I could do it like this:

```php
$tags = ['X', 'Y'];
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$articles = $articles
    ->find()
    ->innerJoinWith('Tags')
    ->where(['Tags.name IN' => $tags])
    ->group(['Articles.id'])
    ->having([$this->query()->newExpr('COUNT(DISTINCT Tags.name) = ' . count($tags))]);
```

Or if I wanted to find all articles that have not been tagged as Z, I could do it like this:

```php
// ...
$articles = $articles
    ->find()
    ->notMatching('Tags', function ($q) use ($tags) {
        return $q->where(['Tags.name IN' => $tags]);
    });
```

But what if I want to find all articles that have been tagged as X and Y, but not Z? I have spent hours trying to get a working query, but I just can't figure it out.

If I combine these two queries, I get the following error:

`Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Tags.name' in 'where clause'`

The combined query looks like this:

```php
$tags = ['X', 'Y'];
$tags_not = ['Z'];
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$articles = $articles
    ->find()
    ->innerJoinWith('Tags')
    ->where(['Tags.name IN' => $tags])
    ->group(['Articles.id'])
    ->having([$this->query()->newExpr('COUNT(DISTINCT Tags.name) = ' . count($tags))])
    ->notMatching('Tags', function ($q) use ($tags_not) {
        return $q->where(['Tags.name IN' => $tags_not]);
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See [Tags](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tags) plugin that has convenience wrappers for this as find(tagged) etc. If there some useful wrappers to add, feel free to propose those as PR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$excluded = $this->Articles
    ->find()
    ->select('id')
    ->matching('Tags', function($q) use($tags_not) {
        return $q->where(['Tags.name IN' => $tags_not]);
})->toArray();
$excludedIds = array_column($excluded, 'id');

$articles = $this->Articles
    ->find()
    ->where(['Articles.id NOT IN' => $excludedIds])
    ->matching('Tags', function($q) use($tags) {
        return $q->where(['Tags.name IN' => $tags]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work great! It's not the prettiest solution, so in case anyone has an idea how to make this work using a single query, I'm all ears.

Comment: Ah yes, that's true. Thanks a lot!